# Associative property of vector addition graphically: Why vector a do not have a derived version of line?

Tags: vectors

While proving associative property of vector addition graphically, everything else appears symmetric except the fact that vector a do not have a derived line as part of the final graph. Is it due to a being considered base?

[image]

Comment: $\bf a$ is the "base" for each calculation of "$\bf a +$" some other vector  (either $\mathbf b, \bf c$ or $\mathbf b +\bf c$). Since $\bf a$ is not being added to anything else, there is no line to be drawn for it.